# Search in a TextView By editviewi in the Dialog

Tags: android, search, textview

i have a little book in my app and i want to user be able to search in the pages . but i don't know what i must to do.
this section of app is simple we have a menu action that after click opens up a dialog and enter the word and after clicking on the search buttonthat word will be highlighted in the textview .
in the xml we have a text view (in the scroll view) and a search button(that opens up the dialog) this is my code:

```
    package com.appp.web.a95;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class Book extends AppCompatActivity {
    int safhe[] = {
            R.string.Fasl11,
            R.string.Fasl12,
            R.string.Fasl13,
            R.string.Fasl14

    };
    int index = 0;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.bookmnu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Fehrestid:
                try {
                    Intent k = new Intent(Book.this, Fehrest.class);
                    startActivity(k);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

//HERE SEARCH BUTTON BEGINS=================================================
            case R.id.searchid:

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Book.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.searchdialog);
                dialog.setTitle("جستجو");
                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                final EditText searching = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);

                ImageButton dialogButton = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        performSearch();

                    }
                });

                dialog.show();




        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    private void performSearch() {
        //Here i dont know what must to do 
    }
//HERE ENDs====================================================

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
        final TextView cap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bookcap);
        final TextView cont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bookcont);
        final Button safeghabl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.safeghabl);
        final Button safebad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.safebad);
        if (index < safhe.length) {
            cap.setText((index + 1) + " از " + safhe.length);

            cont.setText(safhe[index]);
        }

        safebad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                index++;
                if (index < safhe.length) {
                    cap.setText((index + 1) + " از " + safhe.length);

                    cont.setText(safhe[index]);
                } else {
                    index = 0;
                    cap.setText((index + 1) + " از " + safhe.length);

                    cont.setText(safhe[index]);
                }
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps you need to do
1. Create an xml file in your layout named user_input and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/text_input"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

</EditText>
```

2.Inside your method performSearch add the following code

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_input, null);

        mTextUserInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_input);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please Enter The Time");

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
        builder.show();
```

3. Declare mTextUserInput at your class like this

   private EditText mTextUserInput;

I think it will help u implement what u need but keep in mind to check for your own good the API documentation if you want to learn more

P.S. You can declare mTextUser in performSearch method. It depends on what you are trying to do later on with your application.

Comment: first of All thanks for the answer . but i've already  built custome dialog with an edit text and a search button . and the performSearch()  method must search and highlight the word that entered in the search dialog

Comment: continue from last comment ... and the performSearch() method must search and highlight the word that entered in the search dialog in the text view ( that name cont )